# How can a process access memory mapped IO address not belonging to it's virtual address space?

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management, operating-system

I was reading the OS theory in which I found that a process have it's virtual address space (loosely using technique base and limit register for sake of simplicity) But it can't access  any other addresses. But in embedded systems we can use placement new  or reinterpret_cast (C++) to access memory mapped IO address'es, but how that can be possible if we can't access any other address except process's virtual address space?

```
class ControlReg { 
public:
bool ready() const { return readyBit; }
private:
volatile unsigned readyBit :1;
};

ControlReg *pcr = reinterpret_cast<ControlReg*>(0xFFFF0000); // address 0xFFFF0000 is still virtual or absolute physical mapped address?
```

Is there some instruction that makes possible for process to access any address? . I'm confused I guess, can anyone please help me view things clearly?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a purely OS issue, and applies to all languages (including
assembler).  Modern, general purpose OS's map the memory of user
processes, and don't allow access outside of the mapped memory; a user
process cannot normally access memory mapped IO, or even memory used by
the OS.  But this mapping is done by the system: the system *may* have
special requests that allow going around it; kernel level code definitly
can go around it; and many embedded systems, especially smaller ones,
don't have memory mapping at all.

Answer (score 0):

For that to work in a real virtual-memory system, the device must be mapped into the process's virtual address space.  In a Unix-like OS, that might be done with an `mmap()` call on a device file, for example.  This would provide the device driver with an opportunity to create page table entries that associate the virtual addresses with the corresponding physical ones.

(I'm speculating here, though; I don't have experience with this sort of embedded development.)

Answer (score 0):

All the addresses seen from your process are virtual address, at least at high-level language's perspective. If you're running linux, you can `cat /proc/{pid}/maps` to see how your code maps from virtual to physical addresses.